# Cannot get the value of a variable inside a script task in SSIS

Tags: sql-server, ssis, foreach-loop-container

I have a SSIS package that creates a list of strings inside a Script Task and then uses another Script Task inside a Foreach Loop Container to get the values from the list one at a time and do some work.

The problem is, as you can see in the last image, that I cannot set a variable inside a Script Task that depends on the value of another variable (see the 3rd image), because the package(?) assigns the value "Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.Variable" and not the value of the ConstantPart variable which is what I want.

Here's some code from the first Script Task:

```
public void Main()
    {
        bool fireAgain = false;
        string TaskName = Dts.Variables["System::TaskName"].ToString();

        try
        {
            string formattedDate = DateTime.Now.ToString("ddMMMyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).ToUpper();

            string constantPart = Dts.Variables["User::ConstantPart"].ToString();

            string item01 = formattedDate + constantPart + "01";
            string item02 = formattedDate + constantPart + "02";
            string item03 = formattedDate + constantPart + "03";

            List<string> myList = new List<string>();

            myList.Add(item01);
            myList.Add(item02);
            myList.Add(item03);

            Dts.Variables["User::MyListObject"].Value = myList;

            Dts.Events.FireInformation(3, TaskName, description: "Items added to collection: " + myList.Count.ToString()
                , helpFile: "", helpContext: 0, fireAgain: ref fireAgain);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Dts.Events.FireError(18, TaskName, ex.Message, "", 0);
        }

        Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;
    }
```

And from the second one:

```
    public void Main()
    {

        bool fireAgain = false;
        string taskName = Dts.Variables["System::TaskName"].ToString();

        try
        {            
            string currentItem = (string) Dts.Variables["User::SingleItem"].Value;

            Dts.Events.FireInformation(3, taskName, "Processing Item: " + currentItem, "", 0, ref fireAgain);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Dts.Events.FireError(18, taskName, "While processing item..." + ex.Message, "", 0);
            throw;
        }
        Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;
    }
```

You can [find the solution here.](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/5143829/SSIS_Solution.zip)

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Images are painful to debug.

Comment: If you change that assignment to be `Dts.Variables["User::SingleItem"].Value.ToString();` does that resolve the issue?

Comment: @billinkc Unfortunately not. The same result...

Comment: Actually, you're looking in the wrong place. Put a breakpoint on the `Get Current item` task. Look at what the value being reported for `User::SingleItem`